# Jupyter notebook on EMR not printing output while code is running Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr

I am running a very, very simple script in a Jupyter pyspark notebook, but it is not printing results as it runs, it just spits out the output when it's done. Here is the code:

```
import time
import sys

for i in range(10):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(1)
```

This waits 10 seconds and then prints:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

I would like to print results as they happen. I have tried to flush them using

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

and `print(i, flush=True)` to no avail. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It is a buffering issue.  You could also use **python -u** command or set PYTHONUNBUFFERED envvar. python uses line-buffering if it is run interactively (in a terminal) and block buffering (e.g., ~4K bytes buffers) if the output is redirected